# Cast para decimal em LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Dado que não existe `Convert.ToDecimal()` em linguagem *SQL*, como eu poderia transcrever um `as decimal(18,2)` em *LINQ*?

Eu tentei através do `decimal.Round()` porém não está dando certo.

Eu tenho a seguinte query em *SQL*:

```
SELECT 
[nu_ano],
[nu_mes],
[id_projeto],
[id_fase],
'Financial Progress ("Competência")' as ds_categoria,
'Baseline' as ds_curva,
vl_baseline as vl_curva,
cast((vl_baseline / (pc_baseline / 100)) as decimal(18,2)) as vl_curva_total
FROM [Alvarez_Marsal].[dbo].[Schedule_Status]
```

E a minha query em *LINQ* está assim

```
var result = (from l in db.Schedule_Status
        .Where(x => x.nu_mes == 12)
            .Select(x => new Retorno
            {
            nu_ano = x.nu_ano,
            nu_mes = x.nu_mes,
            id_projeto = x.id_projeto,
            id_fase = x.id_fase,
            ds_categoria = "Financial Progress ('Competência')",
            ds_curva = "Baseline",
            vl_curva = x.vl_baseline,
            vl_curva_total = decimal.Round((decimal)((x.vl_baseline / (x.pc_baseline / 100)), 2)
            })
        select l);
```

Transformando minha query *LINQ* em *SQL* fica assim:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[nu_ano] AS [nu_ano], 
[Extent1].[nu_mes] AS [nu_mes], 
[Extent1].[id_projeto] AS [id_projeto], 
[Extent1].[id_fase] AS [id_fase], 
N'Financial Progress (''Competência'')' AS [C1], 
N'Baseline' AS [C2], 
[Extent1].[vl_baseline] AS [vl_baseline], 
ROUND(([Extent1].[vl_baseline] / [Extent1].[pc_baseline]) / cast(100 as decimal(18)), 2) AS [C3]
FROM [dbo].[Schedule_Status] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 12 = [Extent1].[nu_mes]
```

O campo `vl_curva_total` em minha query *LINQ* está retornando `3000.0000000000000000000` enquanto o certo é retornar `30000000.00`

Comment: A sua coluna no banco esta (18,2)?

Comment: Esta sim @GabrielColetta

Comment: Não é a melhor solução, mas você pode fazer esse decimal.round fora da query, quando os valores já estão em memória e antes de você fazer o retorno do resultado.

Comment: Se eu usar o Round dentro ou fora o resultado não será o mesmo?

Comment: Qual o retorno do seu método?

Comment: Qual é exatamente o seu problema, apenas a exibição do valor?

Comment: Me atentei agora que está faltando um parênteses na minha Query LINQ, o correto é (x.vl_baseline / ( x.pc_baseline / 100))

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Sim